# AutoMapper ProjectTo inheritance issue

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

How can I make ProjectTo map different derived types correctly without it casting them down to the base type?

This works fine with Mapper.Map, but not with ProjectTo.

Source classes: (EntityFramework models)

```
public class FailureAlertEntity : AlertEntity
{
    public FailureAlertEntity(int id, string description) : base(id)
    {
        Description = description;
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class AlertEntity
{
    public AlertEntity(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Target classes (DTO models):

```
public class FailureAlert : Alert
{
    public FailureAlert(int id, string description) : base(id)
    {
        Description = description;
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Alert
{
    public Alert(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

There are multiple classes deriving from AlertEntity and Alert, and I would like to map between these two types without the derived types being casted down to their base types.

Configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<AlertEntity, Alert>()
          .Include<FailureAlertEntity, FailureAlert>();
    cfg.CreateMap<FailureAlertEntity, FailureAlert>();
});
```

Test code:

```
var entities = new List<AlertEntity>()
{
    new FailureAlertEntity(1, "foo"),
    new FailureAlertEntity(2, "bar")
};

var alerts = entities.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<Alert>();
```

Result:

[image: nope]

ProjectTo doesn't seem to consider the types of the items in the list, but casts them to the type of List itself. If the type of the List is FailureAlertEntity, then obviously it would work, but the list could contain other types deriving from AlertEntity.

If I wanted to do the same for an object using Mapper.Map, it works just fine:

```
var faEntity = new FailureAlertEntity(1, "asd");
var dto = Mapper.Map<Alert>(faEntity);
```

Result:

[image: yep]

How can I make ProjectTo map types like Mapper.Map does? I assumed they would both use the same configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do that, but there is a good reason why. `ProjectTo` is extension of `IQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`. What is `IQueryable`?

> Provides functionality to evaluate queries against a specific data source
>
> The IQueryable interface is intended for implementation by query providers.

So `IQueryable` represents a query to data source (like sql server database) via query provider (like Entity Framework). `ProjectTo` will build a `Select` *expression*, it will not actually project anything in memory. So it will do rougly this:

```
entities.AsQueryable().Select(c => new Alert() {Property = c.Property})
```

Where thing inside `Select` is expression (not a function) which will be translated by query provider to the data source query (like `SELECT Property from ...` to sql server). At this moment, query is not executed and it's not even possible to know elements of which subtypes (if any) it will return. You can select only one subset of columns, you cannot say "give me this columns if Alert is FailureAlert, but another one if it's AnotherAlert", such expression cannot be translated to data storage query. Now, Entity Framework for example can handle inheritance of it's entities (like table-per-type inheritance) but it has more info (which tables are used to handle inheritance for example) than automapper at this point. Automapper only has type to map from and type to map to.

So given the above - it's just not possible for AutoMapper to do it another way.

Now, in your example you are using "fake" `IQueryable`. If that is the case in real application - just use `IEnumerable` and:

```
var alerts = Mapper.Map<List<Alert>>(entities);
```

or

```
var alerts = entities.Select(Mapper.Map<Alert>).ToList();
```

If you have real `IQueryable`, for example Entity Framework query that can really return list of `AlertEntity` with subtypes - you have to materialize your query before mapping it with automapper (of course this will materialize entities with all properties):

```
var alerts = yourQuery.AsEnumerable().Select(Mapper.Map<Alert>).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Evk, that makes perfect sense actually, should have known this... I guess I thought AutoMapper's ProjectTo had magic powers. I'll mark this as the answer!

Comment: @ShahinDohan I'm having the exact same problem. But that seams not to be a solution to all cases. I try to use AutoMapper to map between business layer and persistence layer. The business layer code only knows about business layer objects. A simple `.Select(Mapper.Map<Alert>).` will work but there is no way for filtering without collecting all items from database. I want to use something like `yourQuery.ProjectTo<Alert>().Where(x => x.Prop == ...).ToList()`. That transforms perfectly to `WHERE` in SQL but doesn't create correct instances. How to solve that requirement?